# FileNotFoundException in XML parsing in android

Tags: android, xml-parsing, filenotfoundexception

Im developing an application in android Im parsing an xml which is stored in res/raw folder but Im getting an error FileNotFound 
Heres my code

```
            Document doc = null;
        DocumentBuilderFactory dbf = DocumentBuilderFactory.newInstance();
        dbf.setCoalescing(true);
        InputStream is = this.getResources().openRawResource(R.raw.earth); 
        try{

            DocumentBuilder db = dbf.newDocumentBuilder();
            doc = db.parse(is,null);

        }catch(ParserConfigurationException e){
            Log.d("XML parse Error:",e.getMessage());
            return;
        }catch(SAXException e){
            Log.d("Wrong XML File Structure",e.getMessage());
            return;
        }catch(IOException e){
            Log.d("IOException", e.getMessage());
            return;
        }
```

Log cat is

```
 12-08 14:37:17.893: E/AndroidRuntime(502): Uncaught handler: thread main exiting due to uncaught exception
12-08 14:37:17.923: E/AndroidRuntime(502): java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{org.example.xml/org.example.xml.XMLparseActivity}: android.content.res.Resources$NotFoundException: File Hello World, XMLparseActivity! from drawable resource ID #0x7f040000
12-08 14:37:17.923: E/AndroidRuntime(502):  at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2496)
12-08 14:37:17.923: E/AndroidRuntime(502):  at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2512)
12-08 14:37:17.923: E/AndroidRuntime(502):  at android.app.ActivityThread.access$2200(ActivityThread.java:119)
12-08 14:37:17.923: E/AndroidRuntime(502):  at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1863)
12-08 14:37:17.923: E/AndroidRuntime(502):  at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
12-08 14:37:17.923: E/AndroidRuntime(502):  at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:123)
12-08 14:37:17.923: E/AndroidRuntime(502):  at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:4363)
12-08 14:37:17.923: E/AndroidRuntime(502):  at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
12-08 14:37:17.923: E/AndroidRuntime(502):  at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:521)
12-08 14:37:17.923: E/AndroidRuntime(502):  at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:860)
12-08 14:37:17.923: E/AndroidRuntime(502):  at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:618)
12-08 14:37:17.923: E/AndroidRuntime(502):  at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
12-08 14:37:17.923: E/AndroidRuntime(502): Caused by: android.content.res.Resources$NotFoundException: File Hello World, XMLparseActivity! from drawable resource ID #0x7f040000
12-08 14:37:17.923: E/AndroidRuntime(502):  at android.content.res.Resources.openRawResource(Resources.java:822)
12-08 14:37:17.923: E/AndroidRuntime(502):  at android.content.res.Resources.openRawResource(Resources.java:798)
12-08 14:37:17.923: E/AndroidRuntime(502):  at org.example.xml.XMLparseActivity.onCreate(XMLparseActivity.java:47)
12-08 14:37:17.923: E/AndroidRuntime(502):  at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1047)
12-08 14:37:17.923: E/AndroidRuntime(502):  at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2459)
12-08 14:37:17.923: E/AndroidRuntime(502):  ... 11 more
12-08 14:37:17.923: E/AndroidRuntime(502): Caused by: java.io.FileNotFoundException: Hello World, XMLparseActivity!
12-08 14:37:17.923: E/AndroidRuntime(502):  at android.content.res.AssetManager.openNonAssetNative(Native Method)
12-08 14:37:17.923: E/AndroidRuntime(502):  at android.content.res.AssetManager.openNonAsset(AssetManager.java:390)
12-08 14:37:17.923: E/AndroidRuntime(502):  at android.content.res.Resources.openRawResource(Resources.java:819)
12-08 14:37:17.923: E/AndroidRuntime(502):  ... 15 more
```

Please reply if any clue

Comment: if you are sure the file is in the raw folder, do a clean and then build

Comment: yes i clean and build but same error

Comment: make sure that you have your file inside the res/raw/your_file.

Comment: yes it is there res/raw/book.xml

Comment: if it is the file named book.xml, you have to change this line of code InputStream is = this.getResources().openRawResource(R.raw.earth); to use R.raw.book

Comment: there are 3 xml book, earth and music thats not an issue the file is present there

Comment: Thanks for your answer I got solution for my question if you want to save the xml file in raw folder always save as .txt instead of .xml 

see this link really nicely explain XML parsing http://www.codemobiles.com/forum/viewtopic.php?t=69

Answer (score 0):

How are you building your apk? If you are using m2eclipse and maven, there was a bug in a recent version that prevented raw resources from being copied. You would need to create the apk using mvn from the command line.

Comment: mvn android:apk - full documentation here: http://maven-android-plugin-m2site.googlecode.com/svn/apk-mojo.html

Comment: Thanks for your answer I got solution for my question if you want to save the xml file in raw folder always save as .txt instead of .xml 

see this link really nicely explain XML parsing http://www.codemobiles.com/forum/viewtopic.php?t=69

Answer (score 0):

The error must be because of this line

File stocks = new File("src/Stocks.xml");

in my code i placed xml file under src folder of eclipse. now try with your code, it will work.